# combine string and html string and display in ui-bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using restangular to get a collection of items from a server.  each item has a description, which is a normal string and a longDescription which contains html describing how it should be formatted.

I am trying to display this information in a single ui-bootstrap popover

I have added a restangule response interceptor like so

```
var addTrustedDesc = function(room) {
            var result;
            var desc = room.description;
            var longDesc = room.longDescription;

            if(desc && longDesc) {
                result = desc + ' </br> ' + longDesc;
            } else if(desc) {
                result = desc;
            } else if(longDesc) {
                result = longDesc;
            }

            room.trustedDesc = $sce.trustAsHtml(result);
            return room;
        };

RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function(data) {
                return _.map(data, function(room) {
                    return addTrustedDesc(room);
                });
            });
```

and then much later I try to use the trustedDesc in the popover like so

```
popover="{{ row.data.trustedDesc }}"
```

but the popover just displays {}

if I change the line above to

> room.trustedDesc = $sce.getTrustedHtml($sce.trustAsHtml(result));

or simply

> room.trustedDesc = result;

then the popover displays the full string including the html elements

is it possible to get the popover to render the html and display it?

Comment: have a look at $compile https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile , you can use it to compile your html in your code or a function that will return this a displayable html

Comment: My bad, the $compile would compile any angular directive in your code but nopt allow you any custom template for boostrap ui popover, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that the bootstrap ui popover cannot handle custom template. I would try to use the custom popover of angular strap instead http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#popovers

Comment: I dont think I am going to pull in another dependency but your link gave me an idea of using a custom template for the ui-bootstrap directive that used ng-bind-html instead of ng-bind

Comment: including angular sanitize and adding a custom template for the popover directive that uses ng-bind-html instead of ng-bind seems to do what I want weather or not I run the string through $sce or not